# Read Kubernetes deployment annotation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

How can I get a particular Kubernetes annotation from a deployment resource using `kubectl`? I know I can dynamically set an annotation on a deployment using:

```
kubectl annotate deployment api imageTag=dev-ac5ba48.k1dp9
```

Is there a single `kubectl` command to then read this deployments `imageTag` annotation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command to get the `imageTag` annotation (given that annotation exists):

```
kubectl get deploy DEPLOY_NAME -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations.imageTag}'
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between setting an annotation on the deployment top-level metadata vs down the tree in spec => template => metadata?

Comment: Sure. The annotations on the deployment top-level are the *deployment* annotations, and you will not be able to see them in the pods that were configured in that deployment (and therefore, an edit to these annotations won't cause the re-creation of pods created by this deployment). 
As you mentioned, you can add annotations to the pod's metadata, by adding an annotation to spec -> template -> metadata. Editing this field will trigger the creation of a new pod with the new annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsonpath for that:

`kubectl get deployment api -o=jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations}'`

The command above will give you all the annotations of your deployment api.

For reference you can take a look at [this doc page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) as it may help.